# Are Circleci macOS boxes too low spec to run Detox?

Tags: testing, react-native, jestjs, circleci, detox

I have created an issue for this on the detox repo [here](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/717).

I have a React Native application which I test using [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/en/) and [Detox](https://github.com/wix/detox).

Locally the Detox tests run with no problems (sanity checked on other dev machines too). However, they have never passed when run in a [macOS box](https://circle-macos-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/image-manifest/build-298/index.html) on [Circleci](https://circleci.com/).

The debug output from Detox makes it look like Detox is forever busy after the initial app setup on the simulator but no progress is made past that point.

The relevant versions involved:

- Detox: 7.3.3
- React Native: 0.55.1
- Node: 8.9.1
- Device: iPhone 7 (11.2)
- Xcode: 9.2.0
- macOS: 10.12.6

A snippet of the detox logs once it hits the "hung" state:

```
    detox verb ws
    detox verb ws send: {"type":"reactNativeReload","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
    detox verb ws send: {"type":"currentStatus","params":{},"messageId":4}
    detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"currentStatusResult","messageId":4,"params":{"state":"busy","resources":[{"name":"Dispatch Queue","info":{"queue":"<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread[0x1112b9dc0] = { xref = -2147483648, ref = -2147483648, sref = 1, target = com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit[0x1112bb300], width = 0x1, state = 0x001ffe9e00000400, dirty, max qos 6, in-flight = 0, thread = 0x403 }>","prettyPrint":"com.apple.main-thread"}}],"messageId":4}}
    detox verb ws
    detox info Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
    detox verb ws send: {"type":"currentStatus","params":{},"messageId":5}
    detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"currentStatusResult","messageId":5,"params":{"state":"busy","resources":[{"name":"Dispatch Queue","info":{"queue":"<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread[0x1112b9dc0] = { xref = -2147483648, ref = -2147483648, sref = 1, target = com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit[0x1112bb300], width = 0x1, state = 0x001ffe9e00000400, dirty, max qos 6, in-flight = 0, thread = 0x403 }>","prettyPrint":"com.apple.main-thread"}}],"messageId":5}}
    detox verb ws
    detox info Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
    detox verb ws send: {"type":"currentStatus","params":{},"messageId":6}
    detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"currentStatusResult","messageId":6,"params":{"state":"busy","resources":[{"name":"Dispatch Queue","info":{"queue":"<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread[0x1112b9dc0] = { xref = -2147483648, ref = -2147483648, sref = 1, target = com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit[0x1112bb300], width = 0x1, state = 0x001ffe9e00000400, dirty, max qos 6, in-flight = 0, thread = 0x403 }>","prettyPrint":"com.apple.main-thread"}}],"messageId":6}}
    detox verb ws
    detox info Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
    detox verb ws send: {"type":"currentStatus","params":{},"messageId":7}
    detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"currentStatusResult","messageId":7,"params":{"state":"busy","resources":[{"name":"Dispatch Queue","info":{"queue":"<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread[0x1112b9dc0] = { xref = -2147483648, ref = -2147483648, sref = 1, target = com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit[0x1112bb300], width = 0x1, state = 0x001ffe9e00000400, dirty, max qos 6, in-flight = 0, thread = 0x403 }>","prettyPrint":"com.apple.main-thread"}}],"messageId":7}}
    detox verb ws
    detox info Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
    detox verb ws send: {"type":"currentStatus","params":{},"messageId":8}
    detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"currentStatusResult","messageId":8,"params":{"state":"busy","resources":[{"name":"Dispatch Queue","info":{"queue":"<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread[0x1112b9dc0] = { xref = -2147483648, ref = -2147483648, sref = 1, target = com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit[0x1112bb300], width = 0x1, state = 0x001ffe9e00000400, dirty, max qos 6, in-flight = 0, thread = 0x403 }>","prettyPrint":"com.apple.main-thread"}}],"messageId":8}}
    detox verb ws
    detox info Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
    detox verb ws send: {"type":"currentStatus","params":{},"messageId":9}
    detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"currentStatusResult","messageId":9,"params":{"state":"busy","resources":[{"name":"Dispatch Queue","info":{"queue":"<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread[0x1112b9dc0] = { xref = -2147483648, ref = -2147483648, sref = 1, target = com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit[0x1112bb300], width = 0x1, state = 0x001ffe9e00000400, dirty, max qos 6, in-flight = 0, thread = 0x403 }>","prettyPrint":"com.apple.main-thread"}}],"messageId":9}}
    detox verb ws
    detox info Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
    detox verb ws send: {"type":"currentStatus","params":{},"messageId":10}
    detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"currentStatusResult","messageId":10,"params":{"state":"busy","resources":[{"name":"Dispatch Queue","info":{"queue":"<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread[0x1112b9dc0] = { xref = -2147483648, ref = -2147483648, sref = 1, target = com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit[0x1112bb300], width = 0x1, state = 0x001ffe9e00000400, dirty, max qos 6, in-flight = 0, thread = 0x403 }>","prettyPrint":"com.apple.main-thread"}}],"messageId":10}}
    detox verb ws
    detox info Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
    detox verb ws send: {"type":"currentStatus","params":{},"messageId":11}
    detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"currentStatusResult","messageId":11,"params":{"state":"busy","resources":[{"name":"Dispatch Queue","info":{"queue":"<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread[0x1112b9dc0] = { xref = -2147483648, ref = -2147483648, sref = 1, target = com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit[0x1112bb300], width = 0x1, state = 0x001ffe9e00000400, dirty, max qos 6, in-flight = 0, thread = 0x403 }>","prettyPrint":"com.apple.main-thread"}}],"messageId":11}}
    detox verb ws
    detox info Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
    detox verb ws send: {"type":"currentStatus","params":{},"messageId":12}
    detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"currentStatusResult","messageId":12,"params":{"state":"busy","resources":[{"name":"Dispatch Queue","info":{"queue":"<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread[0x1112b9dc0] = { xref = -2147483648, ref = -2147483648, sref = 1, target = com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit[0x1112bb300], width = 0x1, state = 0x001ffe9e00000400, dirty, max qos 6, in-flight = 0, thread = 0x403 }>","prettyPrint":"com.apple.main-thread"}}],"messageId":12}}
```

My question is; is Detox hanging because of the low resource (computationally) environment it is run in on Circleci (does anyone have a large Detox suite functioning on Circleci)?

Comment: Do you have an example of your circle-ci setup?

Comment: @AlexChin yeah but things have changed slightly, I put a copy of it here for you https://gist.github.com/Angry-Potato/6ca4373268d14d09c36a5f90f2d07b31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgraded the Nodejs version to < 8.8 and all is now running as expected.